# How to find memory and runtime used by a NuSMV model

Tags: performance, time, nusmv

Given a NuSMV model, how to find its runtime and how much memory it consumed?

So the runtime can be found using this command at system prompt: /usr/bin/time -f "time %e s" NuSMV filename.smv

The above gives the wall-clock time. Is there a better way to obtain runtime statistics from within NuSMV itself?

Also how to find out how much RAM memory the program used during its processing of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `usage` command, which displays both the amount of *RAM* currently being used, as well as the *User* and the *System* time used by the tool since when it was started (thus, `usage` should be called both before and after each operation which you want to profile).

An example execution:

```
NuSMV > usage
Runtime Statistics
------------------
Machine name: *****
User time    0.005 seconds
System time  0.005 seconds

Average resident text size       =     0K
Average resident data+stack size =     0K
Maximum resident size            =  6932K

Virtual text size                =  8139K
Virtual data size                = 34089K
    data size initialized        =  3424K
    data size uninitialized      =   178K
    data size sbrk               = 30487K
Virtual memory limit             = -2147483648K (-2147483648K)

Major page faults = 0
Minor page faults = 2607
Swaps = 0
Input blocks = 0
Output blocks = 0
Context switch (voluntary) = 9
Context switch (involuntary) = 0

NuSMV > reset; read_model -i nusmvLab.2018.06.07.smv ; go ; check_property ; usage
-- specification (L6 != pc U cc = len) IN mm is true
-- specification  F (min = 2 & max = 9) IN mm is true
-- specification  G !((((max > arr[0] & max > arr[1]) & max > arr[2]) & max > arr[3]) & max > arr[4]) IN mm is true
-- invariant max >= min IN mm is true

Runtime Statistics
------------------
Machine name: *****
User time   47.214 seconds
System time  0.284 seconds

Average resident text size       =     0K
Average resident data+stack size =     0K
Maximum resident size            = 270714K

Virtual text size                =  8139K
Virtual data size                = 435321K
    data size initialized        =  3424K
    data size uninitialized      =   178K
    data size sbrk               = 431719K
Virtual memory limit             = -2147483648K (-2147483648K)

Major page faults = 1
Minor page faults = 189666
Swaps = 0
Input blocks = 48
Output blocks = 0
Context switch (voluntary) = 12
Context switch (involuntary) = 145
```

Comment: So just to confirm in the above, the user time is 47.214 seconds or 47.214-0.005 seconds? And the memory used is 435321 K or 435321+8139 K?

Comment: @user_1_1_1 The time is given in absolute terms since the start of the tool, so one should compute the delta time before/after running some command. I think that the memory figure that should be tracked is *Memory resident size*, because the other are *Virtual*  memory figures, and these can exceed what it is actually used by a program. You may want to double-check my assertions with google.